# ImportError: No module named ldap (Windows XP)

Tags: python-ldap

I have installed Python 2.7.1 and python-ldap-2.4.8.win32-py2.7 module. Whenever I type

> > > import ldap

it gives and error.......

> ImportError: No module named ldap

Path is set properly, I have only one version of Python i.e. 2.7.1 I have installed python-ldap module properly.

then also I am facing this problem. why so?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information to debug this problem.

Are you sure the python-ldap module was installed successfully? (I realize you said it was but if you tried to install it using pip, the install command completes with errors because it is missing some header files for the build)

The easiest way to install python-ldap on Windows is to download the binary from: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap

Make sure you download the python-ldap version that corresponds to your installed python version.